# desplegar menu en python despues de crear un archivo

Tags: python, archivo

tengo poco trabajando con python y tengo una pequeña duda, lo que pasa es que tengo un menu para crear un archivo, ingresar datos en el archivo y al final para leer los datos, mi duda aquí es como hacer para que al momento de iniciar el programa me pida crear el archivo y después desplegar el menu, con las opciones para ingresar datos y leer dichos datos.Aqui dejo mi codigo, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias

```
import os

class Interfaz:

    def menu():

        print ("Elige una opcion")
        print ("\t1 - Crear Archivo ")
        print ("\t2 - Ingresar Datos")
        print ("\t3 - Leer Archivo")

    while True:

        menu()

        Menu = int(input("Selecciona una opcion: "))

        if Menu == 1:

            Nombre = input("Nombre del archivo: ")
            Cont =0
            Archivo = open(Nombre, "a")

        elif Menu == 2:

            Nombre = input("Nombre del archivo: ")
            Cont =0
            Archivo = open(Nombre, "a")
            Datos = float(input("Numero de datos a pedir: "))

            while (Cont < Datos):
                Num = input("Ingresa los numeros: ")
                float(Num)
                Archivo.write(Num + "\n")       
                Cont = Cont + 1
            Archivo.close() 

        elif Menu == 3:

            Nombre2 = input("Nombre del archivo: ")
            Archivo = open(Nombre2, "r")

            for linea in Archivo.readlines():
                print(linea)
            Archivo.close()
            exit()

        else:

            print ("ERROR!!!")
            input("No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta\npulsa ENTER para continuar")

class Main:
    mInterfaz = Interfaz()
    mInterfaz.menu()
Main()
```

Comment: si, la idea es que nada mas ejecutar pida el nombre del aychivo para crearlo, seguido de eso tendrá que salir el menu, el cual tendra dos opciones una para ingresar datos en el archivo que creamos al ejecutar el programa y la segunda opcion sera para leer los datos ingresados en dicho archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres que el archivo se pida de inicio antes de mostrar el menú, simplemente sacalo del menú y coloca el código al inicio del mismo. Puedes dejar abierto el archivo durante la ejecución o reabrirlo cuando sea necesario, pero usando el nombre ingresado al inicio.

No obstante unas cuantas observaciones:

- Usas POO pero tus clases son meros contenedores de código  o funciones, conceptualmente ni las creas ni las usas como clases. Python es un lenguaje multiparadigma, es más no te obliga a encapsular tu código en clases o funciones si no quieres. Más que forzar una implementación mediante POO, te recomendaría que dividideras el código conceptualmente en funciones sin más.
- Te recomiendo no usar nombres con mayúsculas para funciones, atributos, variables, métodos o módulos. Todos ellos por convención se nombran en minúscula y usando `_` como separador de palabras. El CamelCase se reserva para nombres de clases exclusivamente y TODO_EN_MAYÚSCULAS para variables que actúan como constantes.
- Nunca te dejes archivos abiertos sin cerrar de forma explícita, el GC terminará haciendo el trabajo pero no sabemos cuándo di como. Es algo que no se debe dejar al recolector de basura. Si puedes mejor usar `with` y el administrador de contexto para ello, el archivo se cerrará de forma segura incluso si hay excepciones de por medio.
- Cuando trabajes con entradas de usuario, te recomiendo siempre validar la entrada, no cuesta mucho trabajo y siempre es mejor mostrar un mensaje presentable al usuario que no que le salte una excepción.
- En principio, usa siempre ciclos `for` cundo conozcas el número de iteraciones a realizar previamente, son más eficientes y más legibles y "pitónicos" generalmente.
- No uses nunca `readlines` si no necesitas tener en una lista todas las líneas del fichero simultáneamente. Esto solo es necesario en algunas operaciones como ordenamientos. Usa simplemente un `for` in para iterar sobre el fichero, así no cargas el archivo al completo en memoria.
- La línea `float(Num)` realmente no hace nada, convierte `Num` en `float` y retorna el objeto, como no lo asocias a ninguna variable lo más que hace es producir una excepción si laa cadena no es algo convertible a `float` Si quieres convertir `Num` debes reasignar: `Num = float(Num)`.
- Evita operaciones innecesarias y que muchas veces causan más problemas encima. Por ejemplo, no necesitas convertir la opción a entero, primero es más ineficiente que operar con la cadena directamente y además puedes causar un `ValueError` si ingresa algo que no sea un entero. Deja la variable `Menu` como `str` y compara con `if Menu == "1":`.
- `exit` y `quit` debe usarse en principio solo en una cesión del interprete interactivo y nunca  en producción. Si quieres usarlo, usa `sys.exit()` en su lugar.

Después de todo el tostón que te he dado te dejo el código teniendo en cuenta lo anterior:

```
import sys


def menu():
    while True:
        print("Elige una opcion")
        print("\t1 - Ingresar Datos")
        print("\t2 - Leer Archivo")
        print("\t3 - Salir")
        opción = input("Selecciona una opcion: ")

        if opción in ("1", "2", "3"):
            return opción
        input(("ERROR!!!\n"
               "No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta\n"
               "pulsa ENTER para continuar\n")
              )


def ingresar_datos(ruta_archivo):
    while True:
        try:
            cantidad = int(
                input(f"Introduzca la cantidad de valores a ingresar: ")
                )
        except ValueError:
            print("Debe ingresar un entero válido")
        else:
            if cantidad > 0:
                break
            print("Debe ingresar un entero positivo mayor que 0")

    with open(ruta_archivo, "a", encoding="UTF-8") as archivo:
        for n in range(1, cantidad + 1):
            while True:
                try:
                    num = float(input(f"Ingresa el {n}º número: "))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Debe ingresar un número válido")
                else:
                    archivo.write(f"{num}\n")
                    break


def leer_archivo(ruta_archivo):
    with open(ruta_archivo, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as archivo:
        print("-" * 74)
        for linea in archivo:
            print(linea.rstrip())
        print("-" * 74)


def main():
    ruta_archivo = input("Ingrese el nombre del archivo: ")
    with open(ruta_archivo, "a", encoding="UTF-8"):
        pass

    while True:
        opción = menu()
        if opción == '1':
            ingresar_datos(ruta_archivo)
        elif opción == '2':
            leer_archivo(ruta_archivo)
        elif opción == '3':
            sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: gracias por tomarte la molestia de corregir el código, solo que tengo poco usando python y soy un principiante, y pues intentare guiarme con tu codigo, ya que si entrego algo así, el profesor no va a creer que yo lo hice jeje, lo vuelvo a decir nuevamente gracias, solo una duda mas, termine sacando la parte que me dijiste del menu y ya se crea el archivo al ejecutar el programa, mi duda es: como puedo hacer para que las opciones de ingresar y leer datos no pidan el nombre del archivo, simplemente al entrar a una opción empiece ya con el procedimiento, sea ingresar datos o leer.

Comment: Haz lo mismo que en mi ejemplo, uses funciones para cada procedimiento o no. Quitas el input en el que pides el nombre del archivo dentro de las opciones (solo dejas el del inicio) y usas la variable con el nombre del archivo que generaste al inicio en el input del usuario para abrirlo nuevamente cuando lo requieras. Otra opción es abrir el archivo en modo a+ y solo abrirlo una vez, pero tienes que mover el cursor al final del fichero cuando escribas y a inicio cada vez que lees con seek().

Comment: De mi código tal vez los try-except para la validación y el uso de with sea lo que tu profesor podía considerar extraño si no lo habéis dado. El with puedes substituirlo por open y su llamada a close cuando termines. la validación, hay otras formas pero se requieren métodos como isdigit de str... Puedes no validar, eso solo era una observación. Ten en cuenta lo de las convenciones de estilo, lo de exit, lo de cerrar los archivos, usar el iterador para leerlos en vez de  readlines y  yo no usaría clases  si no te lo exigen, en este caso creo que es complicarse.

Comment: Si tienes cualquier duda o te sigues atascando comenta, también puedes editar la pregunta agregando tu progreso y dejar un comentario en mi respuesta, pero no elimines nada de lo que tienes en tu pregunta ahora para no dejar las respuestas sin contexto, añade al final. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente pide al usuario como primera instancia que escriba el nombre el cual llevara el archivo .

```
filename = str(input("Cual es el nombre del archivo ?"))
```

Ahora vamos a crearlo asi:

```
filename = str(input("Cual es el nombre del archivo ? "))

file = open("C:/ruta/del/archivo/"+filename+".txt","w")
file.close()
```

Te recomiendo que para hacer el menú en python utilices diccionarios(def) es un poco mas avanzado pero sin duda es mucho mejor a anidar if else. [Aqui](https://medium.com/@BryanMiranda/simular-un-switch-en-python3-35415520bf1f)  te comparto un enlace si te interesa.

Answer (score 1):

respecto a tu menu te sugiero la siguiente forma, es un poco mas comoda de trabajar, quizas te sirva:

```
def opcion1():
    pass     #Implementa codigo aqui
def opcion2():
    pass     #Implementa codigo aqui
def opcion3():
    pass     #Implementa codigo aqui
def opcion4():
    pass     #Implementa codigo aqui


switcher ={
    1: opcion1,
    2: opcion2,
    3: opcion3,
    4: opcion4
}
def switch(argument):
    func=switcher.get(argument,lambda:print("Opcion Incorrecta"))
    func()


if bic== False:
    ban = False
    while not ban:
        print("1. opcion 1")
        print("2. Opcion 2")
        print("3. Opcion 3")
        print("4. Salir")

        opcion=input("Ingrese su opcion: ")
        opcion=int(opcion)
        switch(opcion)
        ban = int(opcion) == 4

input("Presione ENTER para continuar")
```